# Firebase hosting/functions - how get real hostname (domain name)

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have multiple domains
example.com and example.nl

I want to make redirect from example.nl to example.com/nl
But I can't see real domain name, because I get `us-central1-example-name.cloudfunctions.net` in req.hostname

The function is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')


const app = express()

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  if(req.hostname == 'example.nl'){
    return res.status(302).redirect("https://example.com/nl");
  }

  return res.status(200).send('Hello');
})
exports.nuxtApp = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

I couldn't find any instruction how to do it in firebase hosting [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects)

**UPD:** I've found solution. (req.headers['x-forwarded-host'])

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')


const app = express()

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] == 'example.nl'){
    return res.status(302).redirect("https://example.com/nl");
  }

  return res.status(200).send('Hello');
})
exports.nuxtApp = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the other headers in the request? Are there any proxy headers?

Comment: After you question I have tried to log request object and I see the domain name in req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] --> example.nl. 

So it looks like a right way. 

Thank you!

Comment: @Oleksii.B did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @meghs-dhameliya yes. I used req.headers['x-forwarded-host']. 

Example:

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if(req.headers['x-forwarded-host'] == 'example.com'){
    return res.status(302).redirect("https://example.com/nl");
  }
})

Answer (score 4):

**req.headers["x-forwarded-host"]** - this worked for me